# ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, keras

This my script:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=train_padded.shape[1]))

model.add(Conv1D(48, 5, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 100
batch_size = 32

history = model.fit(train_padded, training_labels, shuffle=True ,
                    epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, 
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    callbacks=[ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=3, min_lr=0.0001), 
                               EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=3, verbose=1),
                               EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', patience=3, verbose=1)])
```

I have an error:
ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Have you any idea please.
This is the original notebook: https://github.com/snymanje/MultiClass-Text-Classification-with-Tensorflow/blob/master/MultiClass_Text_Classification_with_Tensorflow.ipynb
When I added my database, I git this error when fitting the model.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your labels don't tie to your model.

Try changing this line:

```
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: I change the above line, but it still has this error.